# DLL file to unrar a RAR archive in vb.net and vs2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2012, rar

I need a little help with my vb.net programming as I am trying to unrar a RAR archive. I have the latest version from Chilkat for VS2012 in VB.NET, but it does not include a `Chilkat.RAR` method.  I have tried using unrar.dll v3.9.3, but I cannot add the reference to my project because it is not compatible with VS2012. It says that the DLL is not a valid assembly and to check and make sure it is a valid assembly. I just need something that can unrar a RAR archive (no password method needed, and preferably only 1 file, not all files in a directory). This has to be compatible with the .net framework 4.0 AND/OR 4.5 AND MUST be able to be referenced in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Pro(VB.NET Environment).

Comment: Take a look at http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/ i'll survive without the credits.

Comment: Also http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/. And just to ask. Are you compiling your app for AnyCPU platform? Have you tried the unrar.dll with x86 platform?

Comment: yeah make sure your not trying to use the x64 version when you need x86 or vice versa, and make sure you download the version that matches your version of .net

Comment: I have tried the unrar.dll for the x86 system and it does not work. Same on the x64 dll. My app is created in vs2012 and anything made with vs2012 can only run on w7 or higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unrar.dll from RARLAB (http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) is a native library, so you cannot add it as a reference in a VB.NET project. You have to use Platform Invoke to consume its API, and that's what Chilkat's RAR library is based on.

If you want a managed library, you can check out http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com.

Sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com is based on 7-zip's native library, so it claims to support RAR format.

dotnetzip.codeplex.com is a managed ZIP library, which does not support RAR, and @Steve should not state it in the comment.

Comment: Yeah but this version of chilkat DOES NOT support RAR in vb.net: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/download/ChilkatDotNet45-9.3.2-win32.msi

Comment: Also, sharpcompress looks like it will do the job! Thanks for the help!

Comment: We are using sevenzipsharp in our server-side windows service. If service runs more than two weeks without restarting it starts to work very-very slowly. Compression that normally takes 30 seconds can take 15 minutes. After service restart it works fine again. We are going to try sharpcompress.

Answer (score 1):

SharpCompress is a compression library for .NET/Mono/Silverlight/WP7 that can unrar, un7zip, unzip, untar unbzip2 and ungzip with forward-only reading and file random access APIs. Write support for zip/tar/bzip2/gzip is implemented.

The major feature is support for non-seekable streams so large files can be processed on the fly (i.e. download stream).

Now on GitHub: https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress